# Current derivative in RLC circuit

Tags: current, formula-derivation

How to find the current derivative(di/dt) at t = 0+ in the first loop?
[image: Original circuit]
[image: Attempt page 1]
[image: Attempt page 2]

Comment: Show the circuit; show your attempt.

Comment: @Chu I'll edit the question with my work

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr that's not home work dude...it's a concept i didn't understand how to find derivative of current at t = 0 +

Comment: @Chu see the circuit from drive link

Comment: First of all, drive links or any other external links to your attempt/circuit are not recommended. You can upload the images here on this website. Secondly, your links are not public. Please edit your question again and upload these pics here.

Comment: @Hazem yeah done now

Comment: Well, I think you have to edit the question (again) so that the reader does not need to rotate his/her head 90 degree.